# Coldfusion - Session.dsn Confusion

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, datasource, coldfusion-11, cfquery

I'm being tasked to help with a slow takeover of a large ColdFusion app for our organization. I'm not finding the syntax or functions terribly hard to understand, but I do have one thing I can't find an answer to:

```
<cfquery name="testquery" datasource="#Session.dsn#">
```

My question is simple: (at least it sounds that way:)

**What is "#Session.dsn#" referrring to?**

As best I can tell, it's not a user defined variable, but something built into CF. Am I wrong there? If I were to take a stab, I would say that it is a generic variable referring to the database that is currently assigned to the site. I have not gone through the setup process  or configuring of CF admin, as that way already done for this project. Am I far off in my guess?

Comment: You define database connections in the Coldfusion Administrator. The `datasource` attribute of the `cfquery` tag takes the name defined there.

Comment: `dsn` is often used to specify a datasource name, which will directs your query to the correct database.  Session is a scope.  Session variables can be defined anywhere, do a code search but I would look at Application.cfc's onSessionStart() first.

Comment: OK, that will be a good starting point, thank you!

Comment: dsn = 'data source name'

Comment: @AlexBaban in this case you are probably correct. However 'dsn' is simply a string and can be a variable of any data type.

Comment: (Edit) Sounds like it is a two part question. What is it (A: user defined variable) and where is it defined (A: usually in onSessionStart). @BernhardDöbler or Henry one of you should promote your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments say, it is most likely a Datasource Name. You should dump it to know for sure: `<cfdump var='#Session.dsn#'>`.

Comment: That is a fantastic idea, I hadn't made that connection in my mind yet, thanks!

Comment: Dump the whole session scope, is possible you'll be surprised what you'll find there :-)   <cfdump var='#session#'>